# Warshall's algorithm for transitive closure

Tags: performance, beginner, c

I was going through this code for implementing Warshall's algorithm. 
I think the time complexity for this simple problem is huge because there are too many loops running here. The time complexity for this code should be \$O(n^3)\$.

Is there a way to optimize this code so that the time complexity can be reduced a bit?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<math.h>
int maximum(int,int);
void warshal(int p[10][10],int n)
{
int i,j,k;

for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
 for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
   for(k=1;k<=n;k++)
     p[i][j]=maximum(p[i][j],p[i][k]&&p[k][j]);
}
int maximum(int a,int b)
{                                                       ;
if(a>b)
return(a);
else
return(b);
}
void main()
{
int p[10][10]={0},n,e,u,v,i,j;

 printf("\n Enter the number of vertices:");
 scanf("%d",&n);

 printf("\n input values now\n");
 for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
  for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
   scanf("%d",&p[i][j]);

   printf("\n Matrix of input data: \n");
 for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
 {
   for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
 printf("%d\t",p[i][j]);
 printf("\n");
 }
 warshal(p,n);
 printf("\n Transitive closure: \n");
 for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
 {
 for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
 printf("%d\t",p[i][j]);
 printf("\n");
 }
  }
```

Comment: Well, Warshall's algorithm is Theta(n^3), so how do you expect to improve on that without changing the algorithm?

Comment: @user3629249 Do you want to actually write an answer, or are you just going to keep writing comments?

Comment: @Barry,  None of my comments are an answer. nor do they address the question about reducing the `O` factor.  The comments are to the OP regarding how to present the code for easy readability and injecting a bit of reality into asking the user to input up to  101 numeric entries and the advisability of checking for error conditions when inputting data from the user.. SO, yes, I will continue to comment

Comment: @user3629249 Then I recommend you [take the tour](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour) and note that "Use comments to **ask for more information** or **clarify a question or answer**" You are providing a code review, which bears a remarkable similarity to the name of the site. So much so that it's almost like that's what the answers on this site are supposed to do...

Answer (score 2):

**Arrays are 0-indexed**

In `C`, arrays are 0-indexed. Not 1-indexed. So you're skipping the first element and running off the back in these loops. You want:

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
  for(j=0;j<n;j++)
    for(k=0;k<n;k++)
```

**Use braces**

Nested logic is crying for braces to make it easer to read:

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
  for(j=0;j<n;j++) {
    for(k=0;k<n;k++) {
    }
  }
}
```

That'll also future proof anything else you add into these loops. What if you added logging? You'd have to go back and add braces then anyway. It's a good habit to get into. Always braces.

**`maximum()`**

There's actually no reason for this function. The logic you want is:

```
R(k)[i, j] = R(k-1)[i, j] or (R(k-1)[i,k] and R(k-1)[k,j])
```

We can just do that directly using bitwise math:

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
  for(j=0;j<n;j++) {
    for(k=0;k<n;k++) {
      p[i][j] = p[i][j] | (p[i][k] & p[k][j]);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Bug

The order of your loops is wrong.  This session demonstrates the error:

> ```
>  Enter the number of vertices:3
>
>  input values now
> 0 0 1
> 1 0 0
> 0 1 0
>
>  Matrix of input data:
> 0       0       1
> 1       0       0
> 0       1       0
>
>  Transitive closure:
> 0       1       1
> 1       1       1
> 1       1       1
> ```

The correct order of the loops is `k`, `i`, `j`:

```
for(k=1;k<=n;k++)
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
            p[i][j] |= p[i][k] & p[k][j];
```

Which gives the correct result for the previous input:

```
 Transitive closure:
1       1       1
1       1       1
1       1       1
```

## Time complexity

The time complexity of your program is clearly \$O(n^3)\$ due to your three nested loops.  Since this is the expected time complexity of Warshall's algorithm, I'm not sure why you think you have "too many loops".

Answer (score 1):

- Use a tool to indent the code properly.
- Simplify `maximum` using ternary:

```
int maximum(int a,int b)
{
    return a > b ? a : b;
}
```

- Use C99 and declare variables inside loops, like:

```
for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
```

- Put spaces around operators for readability.
- Always use braces, especially for nested loops like:

```
for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
for(k=1;k<=n;k++)
p[i][j]=maximum(p[i][j],p[i][k]&&p[k][j]);
```

- Use `puts` instead of `printf` when there is no `formatting`.
- Use a constant `int p[10][10]` <-- Where does 10 come from, what does it mean, what happens if I change it? Give it a name like `MAXIMUM_MATRIX_SIZE`
- Compile using the `-pedantic` flag and fix all the warning, to me compiling your program gives:

```
war.c:20:6: warning: return type of ‘main’ is not ‘int’ [-Wmain]
 void main()
      ^
war.c: In function ‘main’:
war.c:27:5: warning: ignoring return value of ‘scanf’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
     scanf("%d",&n);
     ^
war.c:31:5: warning: ignoring return value of ‘scanf’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
     scanf("%d",&p[i][j]);
     ^
```